# Nuxtjs pages are not updated even if the vuex store is updated

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

Here my code :

**~/store/state.js**

```
export default () => ({
    selectLanguage: 'fr'
  })
```

**~/store/actions.js**

```
export default {
    switchToFr (context) {
      context.commit('switchToFr')
    },
    switchToEn (context) {
      context.commit('switchToEn')
    }
  }
```

**~/store/mutations.js**

```
export default {
  switchToFr (state) {
    state.selectLanguage = 'fr'
  },
  switchToEn (state) {
      state.selectLanguage = 'en'
  }
}
```

**~/layouts/inside.js**

```
<b-dropdown-item :value="'fr'" @click="$store.dispatch('switchToFr')" aria-role="listitem">
                <div class="media">
                    <img width='30px' height='30px' src="~/assets/img/icons8-france-48.png"/>
                    <div class="media-content">
                        <h3>Français</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </b-dropdown-item>

            <b-dropdown-item :value="'en'" @click="$store.dispatch('switchToEn')" aria-role="listitem">
                <div class="media">
                    <img width='30px' height='30px' src="~/assets/img/icons8-great-britain-48.png"/>
                    <img width='30px' height='30px' src="~/assets/img/icons8-usa-48.png"/>
                    <div class="media-content">
                        <h3>English</h3>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </b-dropdown-item>

data () {
    return {
      activeLanguage: this.$store.state.selectLanguage,
    }
  },
  watch: {
    activeLanguage: function() {
      console.log(this.activeLanguage)
    }
  },
```

**~/pages/projects.js**

```
data () {
    return {
      activeLanguage: this.$store.state.selectLanguage,
    }
},

watch: {
    activeLanguage: function() {
      console.log(this.activeLanguage)
    }
},
```

**The problem :**

In layout.js, when i switch language, the data activeLanguage change and the watch do a console.log of the new value.

-> it's okay

In project.js, it does not work, i have to change the page and come back to it to have the new store value in my data.

-> it's bad

Anyone know how to do with project.js to have the same comportment that layout.js ?
Thank's !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that `activeLanguage` did change for you in `layout.js`. The `data` function only gets run once when the component gets created and strings are immutable, so I wouldn't have expected `activeLanguage` in `layout.js` to pick up when that the `selectLanguage` value in the store changed.

You should be getting state values from a `computed` function instead as recommended by the [Vuex docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#getting-vuex-state-into-vue-components).

Something like this should do the trick:

```
  computed: {
    activeLanguage () {
      return this.$store.state.selectLanguage
    }
  }
```

For a short version, look at [`mapState`](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/state.html#the-mapstate-helper).